# Why is the output of function f not seen?

Tags: go

Why The output is only : "Hello World". Why the func f() does not print ? The variables are available for this function. Thanks for your time.

```
package main

import "fmt"

var x string = "hello, World"
var y string = "hello, Joe"

func main() {
  fmt.Println(x)
}

func f() {
  fmt.Println(x, y)
}
```

Comment: Because nothing ever calls `f(..)`. Try adding the line: `f()` inside your main function. I would also suggest you take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/) to learn more about Go.

Comment: This program is from introduction go from Oreilly. The 2 variables are supposed to be available for each functions. But When I run the program only the main function execute.

Comment: That's the all purpose to put those variable outside main(). That way way both variables can be used by many functions.

Comment: @Freddy53 for you to be able to see the output of a function you first need to invoke the function, as a special case the function `main` and functions called `init` are invoked automatically, all other functions must be invoked explicitly. In your program the function `f` is not being invoked. https://play.golang.com/p/RgvS_0zjijJ

Comment: Please correct the typo to be understandable, because "funch y" makes no sense. I would assume you meant "func y", but there is no func y in your example, either.

Comment: So mkopriva what do I need to change in the code ? Because I followed exactly the Oreilly book . And the chapter it is about "scope" . Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Freddy53 you need to invoke the function, like in the following example the function `g` is being explicitly invoked in `main`. https://play.golang.com/p/RgvS_0zjijJ

Comment: no mkopriva that's not the purpose of this tread. It is about variables that can be use by many functions. There is nothing to initial here. And your example shows only functions.

Comment: @Freddy53 does this make it more clear? https://play.golang.com/p/l6CTkNXSEWX

Comment: @Freddy53 your go version may be outdated but that has nothing to do with the question, the function invocation and printing of variables hasn't changed that much, if at all, since version 1.0, so whatever version you're on, you should be good.

Comment: @Freddy53 if you feel like you're not getting the right answers, it is very likely because you're not asking the right question, or because you're not framing it properly.

Comment: @Freddy53 is there something specific you do not understand in the answer posted by Flimzy? Have you tried executing the code in the playground link that's included in that answer? Maybe if you explain the reason why you are unwilling or unable to invoke the function `f` inside `main` we may better understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite simply that you never execute the `f()` function.

> The variables are available for this function.

Yes, this is true, but irrelevant. It doesn't matter what is available to a function that is never executed.

If you want to execute `f()`, just call it:

```golang
func main() {
  fmt.Println(x)
  f()
}
```

See a working example [in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bQJGqxXrahw).

Perhaps you are confused by the fact that `main()` (and `init()` when it exists) are automatically executed when a Go program starts. These two function names are special.  `init()` functions (if they exist) are executed first, during program startup.  Then `main()` is executed, and when `main()` exits, the program terminates.

All other functions must be called from within `main()` (or rarely `init()`, but avoid that unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Filmzy I appreciated your answered. The function f() is called then executed. And the code works fine. But the Oreilly book at page (30) does not call the function f() so I guess it was an error from his part?

Comment: I am not the author of the O'Reilly book, nor do I have a copy to consult, so I cannot comment on their intentions, or the correctness of their code. You seem to suggest the section of the book is about scope, so it seems likely they never intended it to be a complete, working example, but rather a simple demonstration of some aspect of scope.

Comment: So each time I make a function I have to call it from the main function. Well not different from Java :)

Comment: Yes, in that regard, Go and Java (and many other languages) are the same. They define a single entry point, and all other code must be either directly or indirectly executed from there.

Comment: Here what he says : Notice that we moved the variable outside of the main function. This means that other functions can access this variable. The f function now has access to the x variable. Caleb Doxsey

Comment: He just did not call the f() function. And it had many bad comments on Amazon

Comment: @Freddy53 the goal of the example is to show that the your program will *compile* without error because `f` is referencing a variable to which it has access. The example that follows that one, shows `f` referencing a variable declared in `main`, hence `f` does not have access to it, hence the program doesn't compile. The examples are not about the output of `f` being or not being visible, it's about whether your program compiles or not.

Comment: @Freddy53 because the output of compilation is an executable binary. Take a look at the second example, the one that's referencing the variable that's declared in `main` instead of at the package level, you'll see here the author shows the compilation error. It is completely sensible to omit the contents of an executable binary file in a book that's about Go and not about executable binaries.